# Javascript - How to place a statement inside expression?

Tags: javascript, expression

I'm learning javascript and I have a problem I stumbled upon. I have the following javascript code (I'm searching for the name `john` inside `MyArray`, which contains class objects):

```
MyArray.forEach(
  (v,i)=>(
    v.name == 'john' && return i
  )
);
```

This is not working, because I get the following error for the 3rd line:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'return'

My question is, how can I put statement inside an expression?

Comment: Returning wouldn't help you there. Look at [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: why do you need a return value for [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (which does not respect it), btw, it should work without return statement in an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i put statement inside an expression?

You can't, currently. Nor, in that example, do you want to. The return value of the `forEach` callback isn't used for anything.

See below the horizontal rule for your specific case, but answering the question you actually asked:

On occasion, wanting to do some statement logic and then have an overall expression take the final result of that statement logic does come up. Consequently, there's a proposal for [`do` expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions) working its way through the JavaScript proposals process. It's only at Stage 1 of the process, and so it may not progress, or if it progresses the form of it may change, but for now it looks like this:

```
let x = do {           // Using the `do` expression proposal
  let tmp = f();       // (currently just Stage 1, do not use!)
  tmp * tmp + 1
};
```

...where `x` would get the result of that last expression within the `{}`.

If you really wanted to do that now, you'd probably use an immediately-invoked arrow function:

```
let x = (() => {
  let tmp = f();
  return tmp * tmp + 1;
})();
```

The purpose of `do` expression proposal is to make that less verbose, when you need to do.

*(Please don't mistake this for my offering an opinion on `do` expressions either way. I'm just noting the proposal exists and is working through the process.)*

---

Your specific case of finding the index of an item:

In your specific case, you're looking for the `Array#findIndex` function, which returns the index of the entry where the callback returns a truthy value:

```
const index = MyArray.findIndex(v => v.name == 'john');
```

(Or you might want `Array#find` if you want the entry itself instead of its index.)

Note that since that uses a *concise arrow function*, the return value of the function is the value of the expression forming the function body. We could use a verbose one instead with an explicit `return`:

```
const index = MyArray.findIndex(v => { return v.name == 'john'; });
```

Comment: Now this answers the general case, but it doesnt answer the `return` statement in an expression thing ...

Comment: @JonasW.: Doesn't it? See the arrow function (*"If you really wanted to do that now..."*).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can use this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to find the index of the Mr. John? Then use dedicated method [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) for this:

```
const john = MyArray.findIndex(
  (v,i) => (
    v.name == 'john'
  )
);
```

Comment: Don't you think you should have closed here ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret Ah, you mean duplicate. Well it's possibility, but in this case I preferred to answer.

Comment: Yes, I meant as duplicate. But I guess the odd way the question was asked led you to think about it before you noticed it was just a common one, behind the XY one.

Comment: Could be a bit more handy imo: `MyArray.findIndex(v => v.name == 'john')` ;)

Comment: *"My question is: How can i put statement inside an expression?"* This answers the *example*, not the question. (The example is already answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects).)

Comment: @eisbehr of course. but i just kept style OP prefers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't think OP really wants statement inside expression, they probably just doesn't know that forEach is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. Just do:

```
 for(const [index, el] of myArray.entries())
   if(el.name === "john") return index;
```

Or more easy:

```
  return myArray.findIndex(el => el.name === "john");
```

Comment: *"My question is: How can i put statement inside an expression?"* This answers the *example*, not the question. (The example is already answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects).)

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is just a loop of all elements. You can't return anything there like you did. You could use `find` for example, if you want the object with the name `john`:

```js
var MyArray = [
  {name: 'test', some: 'data'},
  {name: 'john', some: 'data'},
];

var obj = MyArray.find(v => v.name == 'john');

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: *"My question is: How can i put statement inside an expression?"* This answers the *example*, not the question. (The example is already answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects).)

Comment: Well, I said he can't. ;) @T.J.Crowder